# which arrangement gets favoured in naive shuffling for a given numbers from 1 to n according to the algorithm given?

Tags: permutations, random-number-generator

algorithm:
a=[1,2,3.....n]
for i in (1,n+1):
    j=rand(1,n+1):
    swap(a[i],a[j])

let us say that n=3:
132
213
231
these 3 are 5 times possible 
and 
123
312
321
are 4 times possible....

similarly
for n=4
2143 occurs maximum number of times = 15 times
and 4231 and 4123 occurs min times i.e 8 times only....

i figured it out for n=1,2,3,4;
but i am not able to figure out the permutation which is maximum possible and minimum possible.

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered, since it's entirely dependent on the behaviour of the random number generator.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Assume that the PRNG is perfect. Note that to get a uniformly random permutation, `rand(1,n+1)` needs to be changed to `rand(i,n+1)`.

Comment: For $n \geq 5$, the unique answer is $n,1,2,3,\dots,n-1$, as experiments readily show. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out why.